# HTMLAudioElement as JS Audio

Tags: html, typescript

I have an audio that I load using HTML:

```html
<audio>
    <source src="file.ogg" />
    <source src="file.mp3" />
</audio>
```

I have also extended the prototype to create a new function:

```js
Audio.prototype.restart = function(){
    this.pause();
    this.currentTime = 0;
    this.play();
}
```

However, when I fetch the audio element, typescript does not recognize it as an instance of Audio:

```js
let file = document.querySelector("audio")! as Audio;

file.restart()
```

I get two errors:

> 'Audio' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof Audio'?`ts(2749)`

> Property 'restart' does not exist on type 'HTMLAudioElement'`.ts(2339)`

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to

- Tell TS that a `restart` function now exists on HTMLAudioElements
- Tell TS that the `querySelector('audio')` will return an HTMLAudioElement, which can be done with generics

```
interface HTMLAudioElement {
    restart: () => void;
}
Audio.prototype.restart = function(){
    this.pause();
    this.currentTime = 0;
    this.play();
}
let file = document.querySelector<HTMLAudioElement>("audio")!;

file.restart()
```

> 'Audio' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.

comes up because Audio is a constructor - a value.

```js
console.log(typeof Audio);
```